# What consumables give me experience for consuming?

Tags: glitch-2011

It looks like [Tasty Pasta](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Tasty_Pasta) gives 12xp, but is there anything else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tasty Pasta does not award xp for eating.

The following drinks made via the Cocktail Shaker and/or Blender do award xp when consumed:

- Bubble Tea gives 10xp, mood, energy, and a buff.
- Pungent Sunrise grants energy, 10xp, and a buff.
- Cloudberry Daiquiri grants 15 mood, 10 energy, and 7xp, and a buff.
- Exotic Juice grants mood, energy, and 5xp.
- Creamy Martini grants 25 mood, 10 energy, and 5xp for drinking.
- Carrot Margarita grants 10 mood, 8 energy, and 5xp for drinking.
- Cloud 11 Smoothie grants 5 mood, 4xp, and a buff.
- Flaming Humbaba grants 5 mood, 20 energy, and 2xp for drinking.

The above numbers will be lower if you are not at max mood.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Glitch strategy wiki is confused. You gain XP for making tasty pasta (I just made one and got 14xp) but I didn't get any XP for eating it.

As far as I know, eating-for-xp is limited to [Sno Cones](http://www.glitch-strategy.com/wiki/Sno_Cone_Vendor). Sno Cones come in Blue, Green, Orange, Red and Purple varieties worth 44, 90, 180, 360 and 660 xp, respectively. They can be purchased in the Wintry Place (top left of Northwest Passage) for 75, 150, 300, 600 or 1100 currants each.

Comment: confirmed in-game that eating tasty pasta does not award xp.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot about drinks!